# Select rows that have the same value in row

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like this:

Table 1

```
    ID - 4PP - woonplaats
    1 - 9044 - Beetgum
    2 - 9045 - Beetgummermole    
    3 - 1028 - Amsterdam
    4 - 1029 - Amsterdam
    5 - 1030 - Amsterdam
```

Table 2

```
    ID - 4PP - Regio
    1 - 9044 - 2
    2 - 9045 - 2
    3 - 1028 - 4
    4 - 1029 - 4
    5 - 1030 - 4
```

I want to select all the 4PP from table 2 where the "woonplaats" in table 1 is Beetgum, the tables can be joined by 4PP. So the outcome of the query has to be: 9044,9045

Comment: This seems like a simple join, what have you tried?

Comment: You mentioned a `JOIN` already, what have you tried?

Comment: Why should the output include 9045? Its woonplates is Beetgummermole, not Beetgum.

Comment: See the comment in the answer below

Comment: Answer is gone, what i mean is that i want to select al the 4PP's with regio 2 (Because the woonplaats is in that regio). But i only have the woonplaats for selection...

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select t2b.Regio from table1 t1 
 join table2 t2a on t1.4pp = t2a.4pp
 join table2 t2b on t2a.Regio = t2b.Regio
 where t1.woonplaats = "Beetgum";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 4PP
from table1 inner join table2 using (4PP)
where table1.woonplaats like '%Beetgum%'
```